# Why is this array empty?

Tags: ios, swift

I recently implemented pagination to my tableview to continue loading data as i scroll. I can get everything to work as expected upon initial load, however when i try to change my platform id, i clear out my array and try to reload it with the new data just as i did in viewDidLoad but this time im crashing will the error Index out of range. Why does the array not refill on the pickerView method as it does on viewDidLoad? Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

My code follows, i believe these are all the methods necessary here

viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.platformPicker.delegate = self
        self.platformPicker.dataSource = self

        games.removeAll()

        pickerData = ["NES", "SNES", "Nintendo 64", "Gamecube", "Game Boy", "Gameboy Advance", "Sega Genesis", "Sega CD"]



        downloadJSON(platformSelected: "18", gameName: nil, offset: nil) {

            self.setPlatformIcon()

            self.tableviewPlatformImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(self.imageName)")

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }


        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    }
```

downloadJSON

```
func downloadJSON(platformSelected: String?, gameName: String?, offset: String?, completed: u/escaping () -> () ) {
        let fields = "age_ratings.rating, age_ratings.category, genres.name,  cover.image_id, name, first_release_date, summary, involved_companies.company.name, total_rating, platforms.category, platforms, cover.id, popularity, platforms.versions.platform_logo.image_id, platforms.platform_logo.image_id, platforms.platform_logo.url, screenshots.image_id"
        let gameCategory = "1"
        let limit =  "100"
        let sortField = "name"

        currentPlatform = platformSelected
        currentGame = gameName

        if gameName != nil {
            searchString = "\"\(gameName!)\""
            print(searchString!)
        }

        var parameters = ""
        if platformSelected != nil { if currentOffset == nil {
            parameters = "fields \(fields);\nlimit \(limit);\noffset 0;\nwhere platforms = \(platformSelected!);\nsort \(sortField) asc;"
        } else {parameters = "fields \(fields);\nlimit \(limit);\noffset \(currentOffset);\nwhere platforms = \(platformSelected!);\nsort \(sortField) asc;" }

            } else if gameName != nil  {
            parameters =  "fields \(fields);\nlimit \(limit);\nsearch \(searchString!);\noffset \(offset);"}
        let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
        print("\(platformSelected)"
        let url = URL(string: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/")!
        let apiKey = "MY API KEY"
        var requestHeader = URLRequest.init(url: url )
        requestHeader.httpBody = postData
        requestHeader.httpMethod = "POST"
        requestHeader.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")
        requestHeader.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestHeader) { (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil {
                do {

                    let json = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                    print("\(json)")

                    let decodedJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode([Game]?.self, from: data!)

                    if let parseJSON = decodedJSON {

                        var items = self.games
                        items.append(contentsOf: parseJSON)

                        if self.initialOffset < items.count {
                            self.games = items
                            self.initialOffset = items.count



                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }

                    }


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                } catch {

                    print(error)

                }
            }
        }.resume()

    }
```

pickerView didSelectRow

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print("\(row), \(component)")



        switch row {
        case 0:
            //NES
            picked = 18
            gdbPlatformID = 7
        case 1:
            //SNES
            picked = 19
            gdbPlatformID = 6
        case 2:
            //N64
            picked = 4
            gdbPlatformID = 3
        case 3:
            //GC
            picked = 21
            gdbPlatformID = 2
        case 4:
            //GB
            picked = 33
            gdbPlatformID = 4
        case 5:
            //GBA
            picked = 24
            gdbPlatformID = 5

        case 6:
            //SG
            picked = 29
            gdbPlatformID = 18
        case 7:
            //SCD
            picked = 78
            gdbPlatformID = 21
        default:
            print("invalid selection")
        }
        self.games.removeAll()
        downloadJSON(platformSelected: "\(picked)", gameName: nil, offset: "\(initialOffset)") {

            self.setPlatformIcon()

            self.tableviewPlatformImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(self.imageName)")

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

setPlatformIcon

```
 func setPlatformIcon() {
//application crashes on the next line, self.games is empty if i print it to the console here.
        switch self.games[0].platforms![0].id {

        case 18:
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                //Light Mode
                self.imageName = "NESLogo"
            } else {
                //Dark Mode
                self.imageName = "NESLogoInverse"

            }

        case 19:
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                //Light Mode
                self.imageName = "SNESLogo1"
            } else {
                //Dark Mode
                self.imageName = "SNESLogo1Inverse"

            }
        case 4:
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                //Light Mode
                self.imageName = "N64Logo"
            } else {
                //Dark Mode
                self.imageName = "N64LogoInverse"

            }
        case 21:
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                //Light Mode
                self.imageName = "GCLogo"
            } else {
                //Dark Mode
                self.imageName = "GCLogoInverse"

            }
        case 33:
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                //Light Mode
                self.imageName = "GBLogo"
            } else {
                //Dark Mode
                self.imageName = "GBLogoInverse"

            }
        case 24:
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                //Light Mode
                self.imageName = "GBALogo"
            } else {
                //Dark Mode
                self.imageName = "gbaLogoInverse"

            }
        case 29:
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                //Light Mode
                self.imageName = "SegaGenesisLogo"
            } else {
                //Dark Mode
                self.imageName = "SegaGenesisLogoInverse"

            }
        case 78:
            if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                //Light Mode
                self.imageName = "SegaCDLogo"
            } else {
                //Dark Mode
                self.imageName = "SegaCDLogoInverse"

            }

        default:
            print("Invalid Platform")

        }

    }
```

Comment: What line is giving you the Index out of range error?

Comment: Its out of range at self.setPlatformIcon().  The first line of that method is a switch ```         switch self.games[0].platforms![0].id {
 ```.  Basically, any time the self.games array is called its now out of range, but on initial load in viewDidLoad it does fill up properly.

Comment: in `didSelectRow` add `tableview.reloadData()` after `self.games.removeAll()` this line and try

Comment: Tried that.  It clears out the tableview to display it as empty, but still does not refill and still crashes at the same spot with the same error

Comment: Where is the code for `setPlatformIcon`? If you suspect that's where the crash occurs, please include it.

Comment: I have added that code.  self.games is empty, if i print it to the console right before the crash I can see it is empty.

Comment: I know you're still learning but you have your view controller doing way to much things — spaghetti. So, I took a look at the repo and I am now wondering how the json comes back and if you're calling that method in the right place. I saw you have two asynchronous calls that  retrieve data, one for games and one for the platforms. Are you sure the platform data is being assigned to the games before you make that call to setPlatformIcon? I cant check the json data because I dont have the API key file.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  Ive let it get out of hand and have been intending on cleaning it up.  Thank you for not totally not destroying my amateur code.  Ive posted the output of the json data from the console from the initial load here: https://pastebin.com/ZUKn9QQD .  I do have additional methods to retrieve data for platforms, but Im not actually calling it. anywhere.  Honestly I dont believe I will need it and it will be removed completely in the end.  The only actual call for data should be the one for games.

Comment: from what I can tell, the problem stems from the downloadJSON method, in particular from the URLSession forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible cause for the games array not being set correctly on changing the platform id is the fact that the initialOffset value is not being reset to 0 on picker selection.

Comment: initialOffset = 0 and doesnt change anywhere in the code.  Im beginning to think its not actually running the downloadJSON method, ive placed some print statements in there to see exactly when its triggered in the console, and nothing is printing out.  If that method doesnt trigger, the array doesnt fill up, which makes sense as to why Im getting the crash.  Now to figure out exactly where it goes awry.

Comment: From what I can tell, once im hitting the URLSession section of the downloadJSON method, it starts having issues. Is there a reason it would work on initial load, but not when called by the pickerView?

Comment: In the code you posted, initialOffset is updated in downloadJSON to be the number of games `self.initialOffset = items.count`, but is not restored to 0 when the games array is reset on picker selection. Also, since self.setPlatformIcon() is called on picker selection - being the method that it crashes, it means that the completion block of downloadJSON is called which in turn indicates that the request completes successfully. You can get a better insight on why the games array is not set when the request completes by adding a breakpoint on if error == nil and stepping over.

Comment: Thank you!  Cant believe I missed that